# Controlling the order files appear in Git

Tags: git, git-plumbing

This is a *very* minor accessibility issue but I wonder if anyone has addressed it:

Whenever I do `git status` the files appear in alphabetical order (as they should):

```sh
❯ git status
On branch feature
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        src/source.cpp
        src/source.hpp

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

However, I would like my headers to appear before my implementation files. One reason is that whenever I complete a bunch of work, I like to do `git add -p` to add stage the relevant files. It would be much nicer if I could add the headers first so that I can follow up with the implementation afterwards.

Is there some way to customize git so that I can define my own ordering of files? Something like "alphanumeric for everything before the period, then `h` takes precedence over everything else in the file extension."

Answer (score 1):

Is your question about `add -p` or `status`? Because if you only want to add your changed header files, you can specify them via wildcard:

```
git add -p '**.h'
```

If you always want to add all your files in the same order of extensions, you can define a Git alias to simplify your life and save you some keystrokes:

```
git config alias.addall '!f(){ git add -p "**.hpp"; git add -p "**.cpp";};f'
```

Comment: Ideally both, but I mainly want it for `add -p`. If I follow your suggestion, I'd have to add all the header files, then all the implementation files. I would like to go in the following order: `x.hpp`, `x.cpp`, `y.hpp`, `y.cpp`, `z.hpp`, `z.cpp`, etc..

Comment: @segfault: oh, I see now. You want sorted by files, but for files with identical name, you want first header, then implementation. I don't think, I have a solution for this right now